# Parametrized tests in PHPUnit

Tags: unit-testing, junit, phpunit

On JUnit, you can use the annotation @RunWith(Parameterized.class) to run a single unit test several times with different actual and expected results. I'm new to PHPUnit so I would like to know which are suggested approachs for achieving the same (running one unit test with many actual, expected results)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use a so called [data provider](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers). Like this:

```
/**
 * @dataProvider providerPersonData
 */
public function testPerson($name, $age) {
    // test something ...
}

public function providerPersonData() {
    // test with this values
    return array(
        array('foo', 36),
        array('bar', 99),
        // ...
    );
}
```

You define the data provider using the `@dataProvider` annotation.